# Rails many to many relation, exist? query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have one to many relation between folders and docs tabels. I want to look whether a folder includes a doc like:

```
q = Doc.new(blabla)

folder.docs.inludes?(q)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating a new Doc like that, irrespective of the content of the Doc, it will never be identical to any other Doc in the database (as far as include? is concerned) as the Doc's will have differing id's/object instance hashes.

If you wanted to be able to compare Doc's based off of content rather than the actual record (referenced by id), you could eql? (==) - see here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F. I would not recommend doing that though.

I would re-think your solution here ideally. What are you trying to check, to see if a folder contains a document by a particular name?

```
folder.docs.find_by_name('blabla')
```

If you get a non-nil result, you have a doc in the folder with the name 'blabla', if it's nil you don't.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try

folder.docs.exists?(q)